# Brezis' Lemma 8.1: where did I get wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm reading two results from Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> - **Corollary 4.24** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Let $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}} (\Omega)$ be such that
>   $$
>   \int_\Omega f \varphi=0,
>   \quad \forall\varphi \in C^\infty_c (\Omega).
>   $$
>   Then $f=0$ a.e. on $\Omega$.
> - **Lemma 8.1** Let $I:=(a, b)$ be an interval, possibly unbounded.  Let $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}} (I)$ be such that
>   $$
>   \int_I f \varphi'=0,
>   \quad \forall\varphi \in C^1_c (I).
>   $$
>   Then there is a constant $C$ such that $f=C$ a.e. on $I$.

In below "spurious" argument, I show that the function $f$ in **Lemma 8.1** is such that $f=0$ a.e. on $I$. Could you elaborate where I got wrong?

---

Fix an arbitrary $\psi \in C^\infty_c (I)$. We define $\varphi:I \to \mathbb R$ by $\varphi (x):= \int_a^x \psi$ for $x \in I$. Then $\varphi$ is well-defined such that $\varphi \in C^\infty_c (I)$ and $\varphi' = \psi$. Then
$$
\int_I f \psi = \int_I f \varphi'=0.
$$

By **Corollary 4.24**, $f=0$ a.e. on $I$.

Comment: I don't think $\varphi$ is necessarily of compact support. If I recall correctly there's a condition on the integral mean $\psi$ such as $\int_{a}^{b} \psi = 0$ but I could be remembering it wrong.

Comment: @BrunoB You are right! Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\varphi$ is not necessarily compactly supported, as to have that condition on $\phi$ you need to have the following:
$$0 = \varphi(b) - \varphi(a) = \int_I \varphi' = \int_I \psi$$
which you did not specify as a condition on $\psi$, thus you cannot apply your Corollary $4.24$.